# How can I return a new snowflakes?

Tags: python-3.x, function, animation, pygame

I've been trying to finish this work shop and the `recolour_snowflake` function should return a new snowflake but my code returns four different things. I've been trying to fix it but it still gives me four different things. And also, I don't understand why it always starts on the side not at the top.

this is my code :

```
def recolour_snowflake(snowflake):
    color = [random.randrange(0, 255), random.randrange(0, 255), random.randrange(0, 255)]
    return [color, snowflake[1]]
```

I've tried to just put my code into something like this

```
def recolour_snowflake(snowflake):
    color = [random.randrange(0, 255)]
    return [color, snowflake[1]]
```

and the result that I get is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Uni/Sem/pyfiles/animating_snow.py", line 79, in <module>
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, snow_list[i][0], snow_list[i][1], 10)
TypeError: invalid color argument
```

I've been confused. And i don't know what to do anymore.

This is my full code for the animation I have :

```
import pygame
import random

# Initialize the game engine
pygame.init()

BLACK = [0, 0, 0]
WHITE = [255, 255, 255]
GREEN = [0, 255, 0]
RED = [255, 0, 0]
colourList = [BLACK, WHITE, GREEN, RED]
colour = random.choice(colourList)

# Set the height and width of the screen
SIZE = [400, 400]

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(SIZE)
pygame.display.set_caption("Snow Animation")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# Create an empty list
snow_list = []

# Loop 100 times and add a snow flake in a random x,y position
for i in range(100):
    x = random.randrange(0, 400)
    y = random.randrange(0, 400)
    snow_list.append((WHITE, [x, y]))


def recolour_snowflake(snowflake):
    color = [random.randrange(0, 255)]
    return [color, snowflake[1]]


def keep_snowflake(snowflake):
    if snowflake == random.randint(1, 30):
        return False
    else:
        return True


count = 0
# Loop until the user clicks the close button.
done = False
while not done:

    snow_list = list(filter(keep_snowflake, snow_list))

    for event in pygame.event.get():  # User did something
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            # Flag that we are done so we exit this loop
            done = True

    # change the color of snow flakes

    if count == 0:
        snow_list = list(map(recolour_snowflake, snow_list))
    count += 1

    snow_list = list(map(recolour_snowflake, snow_list))

    # Set the screen background
    screen.fill((100, 100, 100))

    # Process each snow flake in the list
    for i in range(len(snow_list)):

        # Draw the snow flake

        pygame.draw.circle(screen, snow_list[i][0], snow_list[i][1], 10)

        # Move the snow flake down one pixel
        snow_list[i][1][0] += 1

        # If the snow flake has moved off the bottom of the screen
        if snow_list[i][1][0] > 400:
            # Give it a new x position
            x = random.randrange(0, 400)
            snow_list[i][0][1] = x
            # Reset it just above the top
            y = random.randrange(-50, -10)
            snow_list[i][1][1] = y

    # Go ahead and update the screen with what we've drawn.
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(20)

# If you forget this line, the program will 'hang' on exit.
pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a few problems in your script.

But the one causing this issue is the placing of the snowflake colour tuple into a list.

A snowflake is `[ ( colour_red, colour_green, colour_blue), ( coord_x, coord_y ) ]`.

But your `recolour_snowflake()` function is returning `[ [ ( colour_red, colour_green, colour_blue) ],  ( coord_x, coord_y ) ]`.  So when `draw.circle()` uses it's colour parameter - expecting a colour-tuple, you're giving it a list of a single tuple.

So fix this first:

```
def recolour_snowflake(snowflake):
    position = snowflake[1]
    # color = [random.randrange(0, 255)]
    color = random.randrange(0, 255)
    return (color, position)
```

As it's the main problem.

You are also munging the co-ordinates (etc.) of the snowflakes when moving them down the screen (and they're moving sideways, not down), best comment this part out until you get the rest working.